# Is there a way to use HEREDOC for Bash and Zsh, and be able to use arguments?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, here-document

Bash and Zsh's HEREDOC seems to act like a file, instead of string, and if I hope to do something like

```
foo() {
    ruby << 'EOF'
        3.times do
            puts "Ruby is getting the argument #{ARGV[0]}"
        end
EOF 
}
```

is there a way to pass in an argument to the Ruby program?  It will be best not to interpolate the `$1` into the Ruby code, so that's why I am using `'EOF'` instead of `EOF`, as interpolating into the Ruby code can be messy.

There is one way to use the HEREDOC as a string, by the following method:

```
foo() {
    ruby -e "$(cat << 'EOF'
        3.times do
            puts "Ruby is getting the argument #{ARGV[0]}"
        end
EOF
)" $1    
}
```

and it works (although a little bit hacky). But is there a way then to use the HEREDOC's usual way of treating it as a file and be able to supply an argument to Ruby?

Comment: I might be missing something. But why not write a ruby script directly?

Comment: @EricDuminil there are two reasons: (1) to be able to do things in a different way (2) even the Unix and Linux Handbook authors think shell scripting might be dated from the 70's while Perl was from the 80's and Ruby and Python are from the 90's and have advanced quite a bit and may be able to do the job better. Then, how about if we make short commands using Ruby or Python, wrap them in a shell function, and have them directly inside `.bashrc` and `.zshrc`? We could have a bunch of scripts in the `~/bin` folder but if we have a few short commands inside of `.bashrc`, that's easier to manage

Answer (score 12):

On systems with `/dev/fd/n`, you can always do:

```bsh
foo() {
  ruby /dev/fd/3 "$@" 3<< 'EOF'
    3.times do
      puts "Ruby is getting the argument #{ARGV[0]}"
    end
EOF
}
```

Here using a fd above 2 so your `ruby` script can still use stdin/stdout/stderr unaffected.

If your system is one of the rare few that still don't support `/dev/fd/n`, you can do:

```bsh
foo() {
  ruby - "$@" << 'EOF'
    3.times do
      puts "Ruby is getting the argument #{ARGV[0]}"
    end
EOF
}
```

(where `ruby` itself interprets `-` as meaning *stdin*).

But that means that the `ruby` inline script's stdin is now that heredoc, so that script won't be able to query the user via the original stdin unless you provide that stream some other way.

Heredoc is a feature that came with the Bourne shell in the late 70s. It's a redirection operator, it's meant do redirect some file descriptor (`0` aka stdin by default) to some fixed content. Originally, that was implemented via a temporary file, though some shells, including bash5.1+ use (sometimes) pipes instead.

Also note that in `ruby -e code -- arbitrary-argument`, like in `sed -e code` or `perl -e code` but unlike in `sh -c code`, `python -c code`, you do need that `--` to mark the end of options as otherwise if `arbitrary-argument` started with `-`, it would be treated as an option to `ruby`.

We don't need it in `ruby /dev/fd/3 arbitrary-argument` nor `ruby - arbitrary-argument` as options are not expected after that non-option argument that is `-` or `/dev/fd/3`.

Comment: The `/dev/fd/3` method worked on Mac Big Sur... but does that mean it may not work in some other systems (Mojave... Linux)? If that's the case, then the `ruby -e "$(cat << 'EOF'` method actually might be best because we can supply some arguments and at the same time let STDIN open for the Ruby script to use and more universally acceptable?

Comment: @nonopolarity, to test if it has it, try: `cat /dev/fd/3 3<<< OK` instead. The `ruby -e "$(cat << 'EOF'` approach would definitely be the more portable.

Comment: `<<< foo`,from `zsh` is a herestring. That's different from Bourne's here doc in that here `foo` just makes up the contents of the heredoc.

Comment: Most modern systems support `/dev/fd`. Linux has had for decades. That feature is from the 80s. The only system I've personally come across that didn't have it was FreeBSD where it's available, but not enabled by default (or at least wasn't the last time I checked).

Comment: See also [Portability of file descriptor links](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/123602)

Comment: I gave it a try using the `ruby -e "$(cat << 'EOF'` method and adding `line = gets;
puts "Ruby is getting the STDIN #{line}"` to the Ruby script... and it wasn't able to get the STDIN input... if as a standalone Ruby script, then it can. I also tried `ARGF.each do |line|` and it was the same

Comment: I then tried the `ruby /dev/fd/3 "$@" 3<< 'EOF'` method and it wasn't able to get the STDIN input either...  I think if it can work perfectly, then we can achieve the goal of: we can run inline Ruby code exactly the same way, without needing to create a separate Ruby file

Comment: @nonopolarity, I can't reproduce here on Ubuntu. I can read stdin OK with either approach.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to use this syntax, just include the ruby program into single quotes:

```
#!/bin/sh -

foo() {
    ruby -e '
        3.times do
            puts "Ruby is getting the argument #{ARGV[0]}"
        end
    ' -- "$@"
}

foo test-arg
```

Similar to `python -c 'command'` or `awk ''` or `sh -c 'command'` etc. Followed by the arguments. Inside the quotes you can write multiline text with your code. (`--` is importart to define the end of options, e.g. for the case a following argument starts with `-`, see also this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/624892/216907))

This is actually a shell wrapper for the ruby command, you can use
the shell to filter the input, process the output, call more programs, etc. Also [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables) you can see more about referring the arguments, I have replaced with `"$@"` to refer all arguments, passing from shell script to the ruby command, you can also use `$1`, `$2` etc.

Some attention needed about single quotes of course. If you can, avoid them. There are probably more than one ways to use them, like `\047` or interpolating `\'` between two single quoted strings. Example:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts "Ruby\047s #{ARGV[0]}"' great
Ruby's great
$ ruby -e 'puts "Ruby'\''s #{ARGV[0]}"' great
Ruby's great
```

[Here](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#strong_quoting) some more about quoting.

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane Chazelas for the edit.

Comment: I was thinking of putting the function `foo() { ... }` into `.zshrc` and `.bashrc`... if it is a separate file, maybe it could be directly a `.sh` with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` and Ruby code?

Comment: You have a shell/bash/zsh function, that is calling a ruby program, it executes command `ruby`. Not a ruby program directly. You can define your function, like you say, or include it in a `.sh` file with sh/bash/zsh shebang. The ruby shebang is for pure ruby scripts, not for this case (it could exist at the beginning of the ruby code  inside quotes, but it's not necessary as we call the `ruby -e ''` command)

Comment: the reason is, if it is a separate file, why make it `#!/bin/sh` and invoke `ruby -e`? Why not directly make it `#!/usr/bin/ruby` or `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`?

Comment: For the case you need it. You can have a shell script, calling 10 different programs, including a python script of 2-3 lines, a ruby script of 2-3 lines, etc. You can include them with this syntax into the shell script. There are many different use cases. If you want to have a separate ruby program, just have it.

Comment: oh I see... yes, I meant to add `foo()` as some sort of small program like an alias

Comment: It is the same as above if you make it a function. (omit the shebang-I wrote it just to say this is shell) `foo() { ruby -e 'code' -- "$@"}` and you export the function.

Comment: using the single quote... then you kind of have to distill the Ruby program and examine if it has any single quote in it (and can't add any)...

Comment: See last part of the answer, for how to use single quotes, also see about strong (single) quoting in shell, how to escape single quotes. Also, If you have a large ruby program, just call it by `ruby file.rb` or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter of "-" indicates "standard input".

```
foo() {
  ruby - "$@" << 'EOF'
    3.times do
      puts "Ruby is getting the argument #{ARGV[0]}"
    end
EOF
}
$ foo bar
Ruby is getting the argument bar
Ruby is getting the argument bar
Ruby is getting the argument bar
$
```